# ipmessenger not working in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, lan

---

I am working on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

I have tried installing IP messenger on this and it showing error message like this,

```
FileName:ipmsg.c
Function:create_lock_file
Line:157
Can not setup lock file:/tmp/g2ipmsg.lock errno : -11 (Resource temporarily unavailable)
```

I tried various methods to resolve this.

- /tmp is writable
- g2ipmsg.lock file exists
- issued permission 777 to g2ipmsg.lock
- At start there is two process running with name ipmsg in system monitor, so i removed all ipmsg processes and restarted the application again, no success
- Created file g2ipmsg.lock manually and set permission 777

none of this helped.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: I have the ** Same Problem ** did you found any solution for this ?

Comment: Nope not yet. Instead of IP messenger am using Iptux. Which gives almost all feature sames as IP messenger.

Answer (score 3):

you can use **iptux** which is the best alternative of **IpMsg**.

you can install with 
**sudo apt-get install iptux** command

Comment: This is a useful suggestion. But iptux doesn't have popup features like in IP messenger in windows.. Does anyone know any other similar solution for it ?